# Python Distribution and Packaging, Entrypoint setup

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to play around with python packaging and distribution. I have a script that I want to execute globally so I added an entrypoint in `setup.py`, but I can't get it to work.

Anatomy

```
mypackage/
.
├── venv/
├── mypackage.py
└── setup.py
```

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
      entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'mypackage=mypackage:run'
        ]
        }
     )
```

**mypackage.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, os

def run():
   os.system("pwd")
```

I installed with pip

```
$ pip install .
```

I then tried to run the module

```
$ mypackage
```

I get this error

```
ImportError: No module named mypackage
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this your full `setup.py`?

Comment: @KlausD. for brevity i just included what's necessary but it should have the name and stuff

Comment: Can you reproduce this package quickly and include code for all the modules? Maybe just `mypackage.py` whose `def run(): print("Hello world!")`? It sounds like there's a bad import statement *inside* the package, since you can `pip install .` okay.

Comment: (which would imply that what you have included is less than what's necessary, but it's tough to tell that without a minimal example.)

Comment: @AdamSmith That's literally it what you see in the anatomy I only have mypackage.py

Comment: @e_mam106 I can't reproduce this behavior, which informs me that something you haven't documented here is causing the problem.

Comment: It might be worth checking `which mypackage` to make sure you're running what you think you're running?

Comment: Show the full setup script. Especially the `py_modules` arg.

Answer (score 0):

You should refactor your package in such a way

```
mypackage
├── mypackage
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── main.py
└── setup.py
```

Unfortunately, you need to have full-package structure even for a single script to make it work due to the underlying script-generation code of setuptools. So `mypackage.py` becomes `main.py` in my example and then

```
setup(
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'mypackage=mypackage.main:run'
        ]
    }
)
```

will do the thing.